Loop to search orders to pull the item quantity using the item ID and the date of the order
I want to search an order database to pull the item quantity using the item ID and the date of the order.
My code (ColumnLetters is an array with letters).
' Define other methods and classes here
Public Function GetOrders(ItemNum As String, CutOff As Date)
    Dim N As Integer
    Dim CurrentRow As String
    Dim TotalOrders As Integer
    Dim ColumnLetters(0 To 25) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim asciiValue As Integer
    Dim OrderDate As Date
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim OrderQty As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    LastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Sheet1.Select
    
    RowNum = WorksheetFunction.Sheet1.Match(ItemNum, Range("C1:C1000"), 0)
    
    asciiValue = Asc("D")
    
    For i = 0 To 22
        ColumnLetters(i) = Chr(asciiValue + i)
    Next i
    
    N = 0
    CurrentRow = "A" & ColumnLetters(N) & CStr(RowNum)
    OrderDate = Evaluate(Sheet1.Range(CurrentRow))
    
    OrderQty = 0
    
    Do
        For j = 1 To LastRow
            If Sheet2.Cells(j, 6).Value = ItemNum And Sheet2.Cells(j, 4).Value = OrderDate And OrderDate < CutOff Then
                OrderQty = OrderQty + Sheet2.Cells(j, 7).Value
            End If
        Next j
        N = N + 1
        CurrentRow = "A" & ColumnLetters(N) & CStr(RowNum)
        OrderDate = Evaluate(Sheet1.Range(CurrentRow))
        Debug.Print CurrentRow
    Loop Until OrderDate = 0
    
    GetOrders = OrderQty
        
End Function

The outer loop does not iterate. The immediate window shows the single CurrentRow value and nothing else.
REPLICATION
I tried to make a simple reproducible version of the Excel sheets that go along with the VBA script.
Sheet 1:
Column C: Item Number, in this case I have # DBA6001.
Column R: Where I call the public function, GetOrders(C2,DATE(2024,6, 30)).
The DATE function represents the CutOff variable.
Columns AD - AZ: Where I get a filtered list of dates where the Item# is referenced. For my example, I have
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTER('Open Order Report'!$D$1:$D$196,'Open Order Report'!$F$1:$F$196=C2)),"")
as the formula. This is why I have the ColumnLetters array, to iterate through each column from AD to AZ as needed. I want to stop looping once a column shows up as blank, because that indicates that there are no more dates.
Sheet 2 (Open Order Report):
Column D: Contains the "Ship By" dates, which for this example I reduced to this list.
Column F: Item #s for each order. I used this list for the example
Column G: Item Quantity. Example List
Screenshots of the spreadsheets. The first two are on Sheet1, and the
third is on Sheet2.
One, Two, and Three

It seems to me that Evaluate(CurrentRow) <> 0 in the first iteration.

@Enigmativity My bad, the <> 0 was left over from when I was testing "Do While" instead of "Do Until" (neither worked). I get the same issue when I have Until Evaluate(CurrentRow) = 0

You write that ColumnLetters is a "simple array with letters" but, although your code shows you declaring it, at no point do you ever assign any values to that array...

Your LastRow =  lines shows that you realise the importance of qualifying Range objects with the appropriate Worksheet reference but, in your RowNum =  line there is no worksheet reference, so your Match function will be referencing that range on the active sheet... Similarly, your OrderData = line is trying to evaluate (what I assume is) a range reference but, again, without specifying on which worksheet this range is on

@ChirayuGupta - That doesn't make sense. You can't have something that equals 0 and not equals 0 at the same time. You need to post a [mcve].

@Enigmativity They're not at the same time. Like I said, it was left over from when I was testing a different method. I edited the post to reflect my initial comment

@SpectralInstance I forgot to include my array declaration in my posted code (I'll edit it in when I return to my work PC in the morning), and I'll add in those Worksheet references. Thanks for the notes!

@ChirayuGupta - You said you had the same issue for <> 0 and = 0. I was just commenting on what you said.

@Enigmativity I am having the same issue regardless of if I use "Do While OrderDate <> 0" or "Do Until OrderDate = 0".

@SpectralInstance I just edited my post with what you mentioned. I also included my entire relevant code to help clarify my goal.

The Range in your RowNum = line remains unqualified by a Worksheet reference...
I'd like to see an example of your function being called, i.e. some of your dates are coming from a worksheet where, in VBA terms, they are of type Long so your code might be better with your Date variables declared as Long. Also, I don't think you need your Evaluate calls, e.g. OrderDate = Sheet1.Range(CurrentRow).Value

@ChirayuGupta - Oh, I see. They are exactly the same. Of course if one fails so will the other.

@ChirayuGupta - You NEED to provide a [mcve].

All we can say now is that Evaluate(Sheet1.Range(CurrentRow)) returns 0, but we can't say why.

I did my best to give you a minimal reproducible example. Please let me know if this works.

You know that DATE(6,30,2024) should be DATE(2024,6,30)?

Can we have a screenshot of the whole spreadsheet?

@Enigmativity Oops, I had it right in Excel but mistyped it when posting. I edited the post with that and the screenshots.

@ChirayuGupta - You shouldn't be mistyping. You should copy and paste from real code.

@Enigmativity I'll note that, thanks for the advice :)

Your screenshot labelled this list likely indicates the problem - your dates are all text values so the code can't recognise them as actual dates. They should be input as numbers - to determine the required format for your locale, enter =TODAY() in any blank cell; you will note both that the date is right aligned (indicating it is recognised as a numeric value), and the format for your locale - this is the format you should use when inputting a date in a cell (you should then delete the TODAY() function as it is a volatile function)

@SpectralInstance I tried to do what you recommended and unfortunately I don't think that's doing anything. All the dates are being seen as numerical (If I change the formatting, it turns into the numerical value of the date as intended), yet the loop is still not iterating.

Did you eliminate the Evaluate calls as I previously suggested?
(when currentRow refers to a blank cell then Evaluate(Sheet1.Range(CurrentRow)) returns Error 2015 in VBA or #VALUE in the UI, whereas Sheet1.Range(currentRow).Value will return 0, which is what you want)

@ChirayuGupta - There is no need to EVALUATE a date. You only need to if the cell value is text.

Here is something that I came up with based on what I know and the requirements of your question. I omitted the other part that you can probably add as needed but to make it simple, this code will work with the function you're intending to achieve.
    Option Explicit
' Define other methods and classes here
Public Function GetOrders(ItemNum As String, CutOff As Date)

    Dim i As Long, lRow As Long, ws As Worksheet, total As Long
    Set ws = Application.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row ' count the rows at Col F (Item Numbers)
    
    ' check item number and add if the item matches and the cutoff date is less than the specified cutoff date.
    For i = 2 To lRow
        ' Debug.Print CDate(ws.Cells(i, 4).Value) & " ? " & nDate
        If ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = ItemNum And CDate(CutOff) >= CDate(ws.Cells(i, 4).Value) Then
            ' found the item with date before or on cutoff date
            total = total + ws.Cells(i, 7).Value
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Debug.Print "Total Orders: " & total
    GetOrders = total

End Function

Let me know if this works for you.

AguilarPro

